# show the total number Products in the add to cart popup

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, virtuemart

i want show the total number Products (carts Product) in the add to cart popup

also i used this cod in the padded.php

```
$cart = VirtueMartCart::getCart(); //getting cart object
$dat = $cart->cartProductsData;
echo "Total Product Count: " . count($dat)."\n";
$cart->prepareCartData();
```

but it does not show the the correct number

how can i fix this please ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the count of total products, you can try like this

```
$cart = VirtueMartCart::getCart(); //getting cart object
$products = $cart->products;
echo "Total Product Count: " . count($products)."\n";
```

Thanks!